# How do I synchronize the display of two IP cameras?

Tags: python, opencv, ip-camera

I can't synchronize the display of two ip cameras.

I am a newbie, I can't think of a better way.

```
import cv2

ip_camera_url_1 = 'rtsp://192.168.xx.xx:xx/xx'
ip_camera_url_2 = 'rtsp://192.168.xx.xx:xx/xx'
cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(ip_camera_url_1)
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(ip_camera_url_2)
while True:
    ret1, frame_left = cap1.read()
    ret2, frame_right = cap2.read()
    cv2.imshow('left', frame_left)
    cv2.imshow('right', frame_right)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: And what's the problem with the code as it stands?